# User Authentication in Dailogflow through third party

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, chatbot, mobile-application

I have made a chat-bot in android in which i called google dialog-flow api. In google dialog-flow, I am calling an third part api. Now i want to implement user authentication in android app but not from google account. I want to authenticate users from the third party (the one i am connecting it to dialog-flow).

How to authenticate users?. Can i Dynamically Change the username-password in Fulfillment of dialog-flow or is there any API for it?

Note : I don't want to use google account to authenticate users.

Following is the Android code :

```
final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("9fweerwewrwr",
         AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
         AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
         aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
         aiDataService = new AIDataService(this, config);
         customAIServiceContext = 
         AIServiceContextBuilder.buildFromSessionId(uuid);
         aiRequest = new AIRequest();
         aiService.setListener(this);
```

So here I am connecting android app to dialog-flow and from dialog-flow I am putting url, user name and password in fulfillment for third party connection (Where the javascript is used to detect intents and perform function). so in short in fulfillment i am calling an post api. which will send request from dialog-flow to the third party.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: To be clear - how are you calling the Dialogflow API? using `detectIntent()`? Are you using a library to do this on Android and, if so, which one?

Comment: I am calling dialogflow API in android through  api.ai libraries in android studio and detecting intent ( i think this you assume we are doing in android app) i am doing intent detection and the rest process in third party.

Comment: *Are* you doing this for Android? (You tagged it "Android".) It would be useful if you updated your question to provide as much info as you can - what libraries you're using for this, code with how you're making the call to Dialogflow, etc. What you're asking may be possible, but it is difficult to tell since it isn't completely clear what you're doing now and how the auth requirement fits into that.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I updated the information. now if you have any query regarding the clarification please ask it. I am stuck from long back days. –

Comment: Is there a reason your question and https://stackoverflow.com/q/58936205/1405634 are so similar? You have the same opening paragraph and seem to be asking the same question. Perhaps you can just ask the question once?

Comment: Both are different question as per my understanding you can say that the opening para is similar.